# jQuery and http headers: which property do I need for message?

Tags: php, jquery, http-headers

The following php script receives an ajax request and throws an error if a required variable is not set:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['id'])) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 400 Bad Request: id not set.");
    exit;
}
//do stuff
?>
```

In my javascript (jQuery), I've set up a default ajax error handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(x, e){ 
            if (x.status == 0) { 
                alert(' Check Network.' + x.responseText); 
            } else{
                alert(x.status + ' ' + x.responseText); 
            } 
        }
    });
});
```

I expect to get an alert box that says "400 Bad Request: id not set." when my 400 error occurs.  Currently I get an alert with just "400".  What do I need to change so that the rest of the message can be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alert box is displayed by this portion of code :

```
alert(x.status + ' ' + x.responseText);
```

Basically, you display :

- The status code
- And **the body of the response**, if there is one.

But your PHP code looks like this :

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 400 Bad Request: id not set.");
exit;
```

It sends a status code, but doesn't output anything -- which means **the body of the response is empty**.

You should do an echo from your PHP code, to have some body in your response :

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 400 Bad Request");
echo "id not set";
exit;
```

The `responseText` property, on the Javascript-side, contains the text that's been sent to the standard output from the PHP-side.

And sending to the standard output is where `echo` writes ;-)

Comment: that makes perfect sense. I was wondering if there were a property available that held the text from the header line, though.

Comment: There might be a way to get the headers *(except than the status line is not a typical header -- so not sure it'd work)*, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#getResponseHeader%28%29 ; but this kind of information is probably better placed in the body, anyway

Comment: looks like `statusText` would be the property.  But I will follow your advice and put the error text in the body instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['id'])) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 400");
    die("Bad Request: id not set.");
}
//do stuff
?>
```